# preg_match Regex wont find matches (but it works on regex101)

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regex101 example which works : https://regex101.com/r/fE6rO9/2 (you have to wait a few secondes because it's big )

here is my PHP

```
    $content = htmlentities($contentCode);
    /* correct echo when i copy paste it into regex101 */
    echo $content;

    // copy past from regex101
    $re = "/<\\/form><table class=\"forumline\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\">(.*)<\\/table><table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">/"; 

    preg_match($re, $content, $matches);

    var_dump($matches);
```

but when i run it, it echoes :

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Any idea what the problem is ?

This is the regex taken appart :

```
"/<\\/form><table class=\"forumline\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\">(.*)<\\/table><table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">/";
```

Comment: Please post a clear ***INPUT*** and desired ***OUTPUT*** sample

Comment: The main problem is that you use regex to parse html. Take the time to learn how to use DOMDocument.

Comment: the desired OUTPUT is in that link : https://regex101.com/r/fE6rO9/2 
=> I expect 1 output, 1 match

Comment: Your regex doesn't work due the previous `htmlentities`. Remove it and it will work. ... but you have to use DOMDocument.

Comment: Thanks i removed htmlentities and i does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your regex and it seems to work if you remove

```
$content = htmlentities($contentCode);
```

simply use:

```
$content = $contentCode;
```

---

Notes:

1. Please make sure you read [You can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495)
2. Some alternatives to `regex` are
   [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
   or [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Haha oke ! I will not use Regex to parse HTML. I know how to retrieve all the information with jquery but since i'm using PHP is there another way of retrieving the information ?

Comment: You can use php [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Oh ok that's pretty powerfull to get every information of every node. But When i just loadHTML with $contentCode I recieve a lot of errors. With my regex i just took the part of the html i needed and with the DOMdocument i can access each row very easely.